# Django using wrong project root folder location

Tags: django, django-templates

I just deployed my first project into production. When I try to access it, it fails because the project doesn't find the template folder. That's the error message if I enable the debug:
[image]

What seems to me is that my project is looking for the template folder outside the main project folder. I confirmed it when I moved the template folder to var/www. Therefore, doing that the django admin page interface (css and javascript) stops working. The html still there, but not styled.

**How do I tell django to look for the template folder whiting the project folder?**

Here's my apache config:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess safebox python-home=/var/www/safebox python-path=/var/www/safebox/venv
WSGIProcessGroup safebox

Alias /media/ /var/www/safebox/media/
Alias /static/ /var/www/safebox/static/

<Directory /var/www/safebox/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/safebox/media>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /safebox /var/www/safebox/safebox/wsgi.py process-group=safebox

<Directory /var/www/safebox/safebox>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Apache has nothing to do with templates. If you're missing css/js in admin files it has something to do with static files. Did you run `collectstatic`? Django by default only handles static files in development, not production. Either use whitenose or put them somewhere else.

Comment: It look like you're right. When do try `collectstatic` I get the following error:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/www/safebox/safebox/static'`.
The thing is, in development my static folder was in the main project folder, change it's place does cause any future problem?

Comment: No, it doesn't really matter where you have it. Just make sure settings reflect that

Comment: By the way, I did collect the statics files right now, but the errors still persists.

Comment: I haven't used Apache in years so it is difficult to help. Except your error says it's looking for `/var/www/safebox/safebox/static` but your static folder is `/var/www/safebox/static/`. Maybe that's an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your settings.py add the following lines if not exist:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

And after this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `settings.py` you can define where django should look for the templates - by default it's in directory/of/your/project/templates/

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,

    },  
]
```

But but static files - like media, css or js scripts, well that's another story though.